# Recreate database when model changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In a C# Web Api project I have some model classes (e.g. Customer and Info)

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

During developement they are frequently subject to changes, so I'd like to drop and recreate the database whenever a model changes.

How do you set that? As I understand, for inserting some intial data, there's the seed method, but which class does it belong to and where is this method called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [database initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). If you want drop existing database when model changes, and recreate it, then use [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>());
```

If you want to seed database with some data, then create your own initializer and override seed method:

```
public class YourInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(YourContext context)
    {
        context.Foos.Add(new Foo());
        // ...
        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

And use this initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new YourInitializer());
```

Comment: How does Entity Framework know that it should take the seed method from YourInitializer and not from another class?

Comment: @user2558051 this method is virtual, EF calls this method from base DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges class and if you have overridden it's implementation, your method will be called

Comment: For testing I added a property `public string Test { get; set; }` to both model classes.
In Global.asax I pasted `Database.SetInitializer<InfoesContext>(new InfoesContextInitializer());`

`public class InfoesContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<InfoesContext> {
        protected override void Seed(InfoesContext context) {
            Customer google = new Customer() {
                OrderId = 1,
                CompanyName = "Google Inc."
            };
context.Customers.Add(google);
base.Seed(context);
}`

Comment: However, the columns of the tables Customer and Info have not changed nor was the seed method called. What am I missing?

Comment: @user2558051 where have you put database initializer setting? It should be at start of application, e.g. in Global.asax file or Main method. Also make sure you call `context.SaveChanges();` when seeding

Comment: Setting the initializer is the first line in Application_start() in Global.asax file and context.SaveChanges() is called at the end of the seed method...

Comment: I've tried your answer in a new empty solution, there it worked, of course. There must me a mistake somewhere else in my project. Thank you!